# comments not displaying in ruby on rails blog application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, blogs

I'm trying to display commenter and body of comments model in blog application. But it is not displaying.
Here is the code of comments controller.

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController

  http_basic_authenticate_with :name => "dhh", :password => "secret", :only => :destroy

  def create
    @post=Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @comment=@post.comments.create(params[:comments])
    redirect_to post_path(@post)
  end

  def destroy
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @comment = @post.comments.find(params[:id])
    @comment.destroy
    redirect_to post_path(@post)
  end

  def check
    @comment=Comment.all
  end
end
```

//comment model

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
  attr_accessible :body, :commenter
end
```

//post model

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :content, :name, :title, :tags_attributes

  validates :name,  :presence=>true
  validates :title, :presence=>true,
                    :length=>{:minimum=>5}
  has_many :comments, :dependent=>:destroy
  has_many :tags

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :tags, :allow_destroy => :true,
    :reject_if => proc { |attrs| attrs.all? { |k, v| v.blank? } }
end
```

// comment view

```
<p>
  <b>Commenter:</b>
  <%= comment.commenter %>
</p>

<p>
  <b>Comment:</b>
  <%= comment.body %>
</p>

<p>
  <%= link_to 'Destroy Comment', [comment.post, comment],
               :confirm => 'Are you sure?',
               :method => :delete %>
</p>
```

// Post view

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<p>
  <b>Name:</b>
  <%= @post.name %>
</p>

<p>
  <b>Title:</b>
  <%= @post.title %>
</p>

<p>
  <b>Content:</b>
  <%= @post.content %>
</p>

<p>
  <b>Tags:</b>
  <%= join_tags(@post) %>
</p>

<h2>Comments</h2>
<%= render @post.comments %>

<h2>Add a comment:</h2>
<%= render "comments/form" %>

<br />
<%= link_to 'Edit Post', edit_post_path(@post) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back to Posts', posts_path %> |
```

Please fix this.

Comment: on which action you are rendering the comment view, show the code for this pls...

Comment: Sorry I didn't get you. Please explain in detail since i'm new to ruby on rails.

Comment: I mean the show action of Commentscontroller.

Comment: So the post body is shown correctly, but the comments are not?

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= render @post.comments %>
```

is incorrect. You must render partials, not objects.

I will think that your comment view in `views/comments` is named `show.html.erb`. Try something like that:

```
<%= @post.comments.map do |comment| %>
  <%= render 'comments/show', comment: comment %>
<%= end %>
```

UPD: My mistake: it's correct, description in comments.

Comment: Alex Teut, what does **@post.comments.map** will give you?

Comment: `<%= render @post.comments %>` is absolutely legitimate if you have a partial `views/posts/_comment.html.erb`. It will [render a collection](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#rendering-collections).

Comment: @maximus, iteration over post's comments.

Comment: @khustochka thank you, my mistake. /me has gone away to read guides.

Comment: I was wrong about partial path, it will look for `views/comments/_comment.html.erb`

Answer (score 0):

Which file is what you call 'comment view'? To be a able to render a collection like this

```
 <%= render @post.comments %>
```

you need to place a comment template to `views/comments/_comment.html.erb`

Of course you can place it into another partial, e.g. 'posts/_comment.html.erb` but then you'll have to be more explicit:

```
<%= render :partial => 'posts/comment', :collection => @post.comments %>
```

(Mind there is an underscore in the file name, but not in the 'partial path' passed to render)